# GUID with lowercase symbols in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, global-id

I wonder is it possible to get lowercase GUID in attribute table for my feature class and how to do that?
So, when I calculate appropriate field (type - guid) with a following script:

```
def ID():
  import uuid
  return '{' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '}'
```

I get uppercase string, like that: `{CC82E261-1B32-4189-A22F-4FD33C0A5872}`. But I need `{cc82e261-1b32-4189-a22f-4fd33c0a5872}`.

I tried to apply function `!globalid!.lower()` (works only in editing mode), but when I try to save it, ArcMap returns uppercase string.

Comment: No, ArcObjects stores and compares UUID objects in uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

Actually now I see how to solve it - to create text field instead of GUID, then calculate it as usual:

```
def ID():
  import uuid
  return '{' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '}'
```